# I do not inherit reputation from SO on MSO

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shouldn't my Meta Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow reputations be the same?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66939/shouldnt-my-meta-stack-overflow-and-stack-overflow-reputations-be-the-same)

I have a rep of 139 (at the time of writing) on SO. Reading the blog, it says that

> These sites will have a shared reputation system, so you “inherit” your reputation entirely from the parent site — while you can vote as expected on meta, no reputation accrues from there. And of course there will be shared, automatic login; this is easy when you have a login cookie at the parent domain.

But I can only see a reputation of 13.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things you have to know:

This meta (meta.stackoverflow.com that is) is special and does have its own reputation. As it serves as a `meta of metas` as well, the meta for all meta questions encompassing all SE sites, and because it started that way. In short: you can and have to earn your own reputation here, without inheriting from stackoverflow.com.

For all other meta sites, the blog statement is true. But there is a possible time lag so there might be short time periods that the meta site shows less reputation than its corresponding parent site.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, you found [the blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/) where Jeff talks about implementing per-site metas and chat hypothetically. The [initial announcement blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/) came three months later and stated:

> **For now we are leaving meta.stackoverflow.com grandfathered in, as-is, with no changes; it’s still a standalone community with a standalone reputation system.** We think Stack Overflow is large enough to justify this, and it just so happens that Stack Overflow is also the name of the company, too. Meta Stack Overflow will serve as the “National Capital” where we process feedback not just for Stack Overflow but for the core engine itself — while the smaller meta sites are akin to regional or state capitals.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: (Normally I wouldn't answer and vote to close, but the other answer at the other question is partially outdated; I've left a note there.)

Comment: actaully, i wouldn't even had asked this question, if i wasn't googling on SO badges, which led me to that post.